# Django project hang on the production server

Tags: django, production

I have put an updated version of the previous django project on to the server running httpd, wsgi. When I tried to open the site, the server just hang up here, after more than 5 minutes gives me 500 error. I have checked apache error log, nothing suspicious shows up. When I restored the previous version, it works fine.

In the updated version, I only add one application which using rpy2 to do some statistics.
By the way, everything is fine using the development server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: We're going to need a __lot__ more info than that to help you. The fact that it works in development is pretty meaningless, since each environment may not be set up the same. Most likely, you're missing a package on your production server that you have on your development environment. You might want to try turning DEBUG on temporarily just to get the actual error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the only Python site on that Apache and presuming you are using mod_wsgi, try adding:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

The third party module you are using likely has a C extension component which isn't implemented so as to be used in Python sub interpreters.

That directive forces uses of the main Python interpreter.

See documentation:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

Comment: I should read the document more carefully.